# C++ Pointers, references and AVL Tree

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, reference, tree

I am a college student and as my final task I have to create AVL Tree dictionary. I am trying to write it myself, I managed to write a lot of it already but I have one problem. When I am using all my getters and setters for random nodes or even vector of them, it works. But when I am trying to setRoot inside of Tree method, it fails. I mean, it works once but once I am trying to work with root calling it with avl.getRoot or as root in my implementation, it fails. My program is crashing. It's the hardest program I ever worked on. Could you solve my problem and give me some hints about important stuff ? Thank you in advance.

Main.cpp - Tests

```
  Node n1("clown",1);
    Node n2("cat",1);
    Node n3("kid",1);
    Node n4("wasp",1);
    n1.setLSon(&n2);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<n1.getLSon().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    n1.setRSon(&n3);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<n1.getRSon().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    n1.setParent(&n4);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<n1.getParent().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    if(n2.hasLSon)
    n2.getLSon();
    else
    std::cout<<"n2 does not have a left son"<<std::endl;
    AVL_Tree avl;
    avl.addNode("cirrus",1);
    avl.addNode("monkey",1);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<avl.branches[0].getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<avl.branches[1].getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    avl.branches[0].setLSon(&avl.branches[1]);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<avl.branches[0].getLSon().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    avl.branches[1].setParent(&avl.branches[0]);
    std::cout<<"ENG: "<<avl.branches[1].getParent().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
/*Error is being called here*/
    **std::cout<<"ROOT: "<<avl.getRoot().getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;** 
}
```

Tree class : Problematic function

```
AVL_Tree::AVL_Tree()
{
    root=NULL;
}

void AVL_Tree::sort()
{

}

Node AVL_Tree::getRoot()
{
    return *root;
}

void AVL_Tree::addNode(std::string eng,int count)
{
    int i=0;
    branches.push_back(Node(eng,count));
    for(i;i<branches.size();i++)
    {
        if(branches[i].getWord().getEng()==eng)
        break;
    }
    if(branches.size()==1)
    {
    root=&(branches[i]);
    std::cout<<"ROOT DODANY"<<endl;
    std::cout<<root->getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    std::cout<<"ROOTEM JEST: "<<root->getWord().getEng()<<std::endl;
    if(!isBinary());
    sort();
}
```

Tree Class

```
class AVL_Tree
{
    public:
                                AVL_Tree();
            void                sort();
            void                addNode(std::string eng,int count);
            void                deleteNode(std::string eng);
            Node                findNode(std::string eng);
            Node                getRoot();
            bool                isBinary();
            bool                isNode(std::string eng);
            std::vector<Node>   branches;

    private:
            Node                *root;
            int                 leftFactor;
            int                 rightFactor;

};
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(std::string eng,int count):word(eng,count)
{
    parent=NULL;
    l_son=NULL;
    r_son=NULL;
    hasLSon=false;
    hasRSon=false;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    parent=NULL;
    l_son=NULL;
    r_son=NULL;
}

Word Node::getWord()
{
    return word;
}

Node Node::getLSon()
{
    return *l_son;
}

Node Node::getRSon()
{
    return *r_son;
}

Node Node::getParent()
{
    return *parent;
}

void Node::setLSon(Node *n)
{
    l_son=n;
    hasLSon=true;
}

void Node::setRSon(Node *n)
{
    r_son=n;
    hasRSon=true;
}

void Node::setParent(Node *n)
{
    parent=n;
}
```

Node.h

```
class Node
{
    public:
                            Node(std::string eng,int count);
                            ~Node();
            Word            getWord();
            Node            getLSon();
            Node            getRSon();
            Node            getParent();
            void            setLSon(Node *node);
            void            setRSon(Node *node);
            void            setParent(Node *node);
            bool            hasLSon;
            bool            hasRSon;
    private:
            Node            *parent;
            Node            *l_son;
            Node            *r_son;
            Word            word;
};
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to reflect the fact that binary tree operations should be involved. It is probably better to write an implementation for a binary tree first, and then extend that to an AVL tree.

Comment: I know, I read about it. First I am going to write it as BST and then use function to sort things and make it AVL

Comment: Binary (search) trees (AVL-trees, Red-Black-trees as special cases) are not sorted by calling a sort() function since the data is inserted to the three so that ordering is preserved in the tree structure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `addNode` you assign a pointer to an element of `branches` to `root`.  A later call to `addNode` will add a new branch, reallocate the memory for the vector, and invalidate the `root` pointer.  This results in the later crash when you try to use this invalid pointer.

You also have a semicolon after an if statement at the end of addNode that I don't think you want to be there.  Compile with all the warnings turned on to be notified about things like this.

Comment: How can I get it done ? Is there any way to make it reallocate pointer whenever root is reallocated as well ? Shouldn't I use vector of Nodes ? What else ?

Comment: @Advent You can reassign `root` every time you add a node.

Comment: I think I have an idea how to fix it. Thanks for your response.